# Access an element appended after DOM has loaded

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I am creating an Input box and a submit button after the DOM has loaded but I can't seem to access them after appending

```
textInput = document.createElement('input');

textInput.setAttribute("id", "myMessage");
textInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
textInput.setAttribute("name", "message");

submitButton = document.createElement('input')

submitButton.setAttribute("id", "sendbutton");
submitButton.setAttribute("type", "submit");
submitButton.setAttribute("name", "submit");
submitButton.setAttribute("value", "Send");

document.getElementById("msgInput").append(textInput)
document.getElementById("msgInput").append(submitButton)
```

I am trying to access it this way to capture the events `keypress`, `keyup` and `onclick`.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.getElementById("myMessage").addEventListener('keypress', handleKeyPress);
    document.getElementById("myMessage").addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);

    document.querySelector('#sendbutton').onclick = () => {
        var data = {'msg': document.querySelector('#myMessage').value, 'username': username };
        append_msgs(data);
        document.querySelector('#myMessage').value = '';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `console.log(document.querySelector('#myMessage'))` inside your function, and see what that returns. While it doesn't fix your issue, it might help you use the Inspector Tools (<kbd>F12</kbd> in Chrome) Console in order to figure out what's going on. Have you tried using `getElementById` instead of `querySelector` for testing purposes?